# Why am I receiving the error "Attempt to Apply Non-Function"

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
pdf=function(x) {
  if (x<=1 && x>2) 0 
  else if (1.5>x && x>1) (4*(x-1))
  else (x>=1.5 && x<=2) (4*(2-x))
}
```

Where I'm attempting to create a function of a probability density function and calculating the density at `x= 1.25`, `x=1.75`, `x=1.95`. It runs through with no problem and calculates the first value of `x=1.25`. However, when attempting to calculate the values `x=1.75` and `x=1.95`, it returns with the error message:

> Error in (x >= 1.5 && x <= 2)(4 * (2 - x)) : 
>     attempt to apply non-function

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've already attempted to remove the brackets around `(4*(x-1))` and `(4*(2-x))`, both don't solve the issue and the latter returns the error of an unexpected numeric constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is, that `else` does not use a conditional statement, and is only ever executed if all other `if` statements are `false`.

You have to add an `else if` statement to your final `else`, so that the conditional is actually used.

Edit: As @Shree pointed out in the comments, your initial `if` statement will never be reached, and should be an `OR` operator rather than an `AND`

```
pdf=function(x) {
  if (x<=1 || x>2) 0 
  else if (1.5>x && x>1) (4*(x-1))
  else if (x>=1.5 && x<=2) (4*(2-x))
}
```

As pointed out by @Tim Biegeleisen in the comments, the final `else if` may not particularly be necessary, and you can do the following instead

```
pdf=function(x) {
  if (x<=1 || x>2) 0 
  else if (1.5>x && x>1) (4*(x-1))
  else (4*(2-x))
}
```

Comment: The last condition might as well just be `else`.

Comment: How will `x<=1 && x>2` ever be `TRUE`?

Comment: I have edited the answer to incorporate these facts, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here are two vectorized ways, one with `ifelse`, the other with logical indices.

```
pdf <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x <= 1 | x > 2, 0, 
         ifelse(1 < x & x < 1.5, 4*(x - 1), 4*(2 - x)
         )
  )
}

pdf2 <- function(x){
  i <- 1 < x & x < 1.5
  j <- 1.5 <= x & x <= 2
  y <- rep(0, length(x))
  y[i] <- 4*(x[i] - 1)
  y[j] <- 4*(2 - x[j])
  y
}

X <- seq(-1, 3, by = 0.1)
identical(pdf(X), pdf2(X))
#[1] TRUE
```